# Archimedes’ and  Galileo’s spirals in one equation.

Tags: reference-request, differential-equations, dg.differential-geometry

The differential equation in polar coordinates
$r'^2+r^2=(kt)^2$, $r(t=0)=0$, k- Const, for large $t$ presents  Archimedes’ Spiral and Galileo's spiral for $t \to 0$.

I find it surprisingly, however I failed to find the fact in literature (some more details available at  [Analytical solutions of a differential equation (from Archimedes' Spiral)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54393/analytical-solutions-of-a-differential-equation-from-archimedes-spiral) ).

So, I wonder if you know where the first publication of the equation appeared and what the context of the research was?
I guess it was related to optic research.
Any reference and ideas are highly welcomed.

Thank you in advance.